# jQuery UI Tabs adding extra tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

So I am utilizing jQuery UI's tabs feature and it works just fine, however everytime I click my "Add Tab" button to dynamically add a tab, it pushes my content down of the currently selected tab. And when it adds a tab, it skips a tab ID. (i.e. #ui-tabs-1, #ui-tabs-3, #ui-tabs-5). Looking through Chrome dev tools I noticed it was basically adding an extra container for each new tab. So if I added a tab the area where it gets pushed down would be #ui-tabs-2 and the actual new tab would be #ui-tabs-3. This doesn't happen in the UI tabs demo so I am unsure where I am going wrong.

Here is a fiddle of what's happening to better show you: http://jsfiddle.net/zKxYb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the `select:` method which was calling the "add" twice causing the content to be pushed down.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below style in your head tag

```
 #tabs li .ui-icon-close {
float: left;
margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zKxYb/3/

Comment: That helped style my close buttons more, but the problem still exists.